# laravel - mysql - how to migrate tables

Tags: mysql, laravel

my problem ... i can't migrate from mysql to laravel 
i am working on MySQL database and i have a lot of tables i tried to migrate those table to laravel but it doesn't work

my steps was like that:
1-create the table in mysql database 
2-opened laravel and write in the .env file the database credentials then i write .. `php artisan migrate` in the cmd

it says nothing to migrate

all i want is to have the same tables in mysql database to be in my laravel project

Comment: `php artisan migrate` command is for migrating from migration files into database, not the opposite way.

Comment: I have not tried it myself but https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator might do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is `migrations` table in your database which contains the names of the migrations that were already run and exist. So what you need is just to create the `database` with **no tables** in it, create your migrations and run `php artisan migrate` this will run all of your migration files and will create the tables for you.

Comment: can i do it the opposite  way

Comment: That's a lot of manual work. You can create empty database, run `php artisan migrate:install` this will create the `migrations` table, but then you will need to add each migration file in the table by hand, because you will already have the tables created so no migration needs to run automatically.